# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._sockJS is not a constructor in my vue 3 vite application

Tags: vuejs3, sockjs, centrifuge

I am attempting to utilize Centrifugo along with SockJS-client to monitor the server connection status. The versions I am currently using for Centrifugo and SockJS-client are 'centrifuge': '^1.5.0' and 'sockjs-client': '^1.6.1' respectively.

My goal is to determine whether the server connection is established or disconnected using Centrifugo and SockJS-client. Below is the code from my `centrifugo.service.js` file.

````
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Centrifuge from "centrifuge";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { useRoute, useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useNotification } from "@kyvg/vue3-notification";
import { useHelper } from "@/services/helper.sevice.js";
import { useUtilities } from "@/services/utilities.js";


export const useCentrifuge = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const router = useRouter();
  const route = useRoute();
  const { notify } = useNotification();

  const { validateResponse, ping } = useHelper();
  const { getPublicPath, getCentrifugePath } = useUtilities();

  const url = getCentrifugePath();

  let connection = null;

  const connectionStatus = ref("disconnected");

  const getNotificationMessage = (notice) => {
    const array = notice.split("|");
    let notificationMessage = array[1];

    if (!notificationMessage === undefined) {
      notificationMessage = "";
    }

    return notificationMessage;
  };

  const callbacks = () => {
    return {
      message: function (message) {
        console.log(message.data.clear, document.hidden);

        if (
          message.data.clear &&
          message.data.clear === "user" &&
          document.hidden
        ) {
          store.reset();
          store.dispatch("login/updateStopLogin", true);
          localStorage.setItem("stopLogin", "true");
          window.location.href = window.location.href.split("#")[0];
          return;
        }
        if (
          message.data.clear &&
          (message.data.clear === "chat" || message.data.clear === "all") &&
          message.data.id
        ) {
          (async () => {
            await refreshListFromCallback();
          })();

          const currentContactId = message.data.id;

          setTimeout(async () => {
            let response = await getChatItems(currentContactId);

            if (response.status == 200) {
              response = await validateResponse(response);
              let temp = [];
              temp =
                response.data && response.data.items ? response.data.items : [];

              if (response.data) {
                const selectedCurrentContactId =
                  store.getters[`${route.name}/getCurrentContactId`]();

                if (currentContactId === selectedCurrentContactId) {
                  store.dispatch(`${route.name}/updateChatItems`, temp);
                }
              } else {
                router.push(response.error.path);
                return;
              }
            }
          }, 300);
        }

        setTimeout(async () => {
          const isDesktop =
            window.Notification && Notification.permission === "granted";

          if (isDesktop && message.data.notice) {
            const notification = new Notification("Traktel", {
              body: await getNotificationMessage(message.data.notice),
              icon: `${getPublicPath()}img/icons/t_logo.png`,
              requireInteraction: true,
            });

            notification.onclick = function () {
              window.focus();
            };
          } else if (message.data.notice) {
            if (!isDesktop) {
              const showNotifications = store.getters[
                "traktel/getCurrentShowNotifications"
              ]
                ? store.getters["traktel/getCurrentShowNotifications"]()
                : false;

              if (showNotifications) {
                const text = await getNotificationMessage(message.data.notice);
                notify({
                  title: "Traktel",
                  text,
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }, 100);
      },
      join: function (message) {
        console.log("join", message);
      },
      leave: function (message) {
        console.log("leave", message);
      },
      subscribe: function (context) {
        console.log("subscribe", context);
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log("error", err);
        ping();
      },
      unsubscribe: function (context) {
        console.log("unsubscribe", context);
      },
    };
  };

  const connect = async () => {
    const channelData = store.getters["login/getChannelData"]();

    if (
      channelData &&
      channelData.mqUser != "" &&
      channelData.mqTimestamp != "" &&
      channelData.mqToken != ""
    ) {
      console.log("SockJS URL:", url);
      const sock = new SockJS(url);

      console.log("Centrifuge URL:", url);
      const centrifuge = new Centrifuge({
        url,
        user: channelData.mqUser,
        timestamp: channelData.mqTimestamp?.toString(),
        token: channelData.mqToken,
        debug: true,
      });

      console.log("connecting to sockJS...");

      let subscription = null;

      sock.onopen = () => {
        console.log("opened");
      };

      console.log("unsubscribing....");
      if (subscription !== null) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }

      console.log("subscribing....");
      subscription = centrifuge.subscribe(
        channelData.mqUser?.trim(),
        callbacks()
      );

      centrifuge.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("connected");
        connection = centrifuge;
        connectionStatus.value = connection._status;
        console.log(" connectionStatus.value,,,,,,,", connectionStatus.value);
        store.dispatch(
          "traktel/updateCentrifugoConnectionStatus",
          connection._status
        );
      });

      centrifuge.on("error", (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        ping();
      });

      centrifuge.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("disconnect");
        connection = centrifuge;
        connectionStatus.value = connection._status;
        console.log(" connectionStatus.value,,,,,,,", connectionStatus.value);

        store.dispatch(
          "traktel/updateCentrifugoConnectionStatus",
          connection._status
        );
        ping();
      });

      centrifuge.connect();

      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        centrifuge.on("connect", resolve);
      });

      connectionStatus.value = centrifuge.isConnected()
        ? "connected"
        : "disconnected";

      console.log("centrifuge.connect()...........", connectionStatus.value);
    }
  };

  const connectToMessageServer = async () => {
    await disconnectFromMessageServer();
    const status = await connect();
    console.log("connectionStatushghghgh", status);
    return status;
  };

  watch(connectionStatus, (newStatus) => {
    console.log("connectionStatus changed:", newStatus);
  });

  const disconnectFromMessageServer = async () => {
    console.log("disconnecting centrifugo...");
    if (connection !== null) {
      connection.disconnect();
      store.dispatch("traktel/updateCentrifugoConnectionStatus", undefined);
    }
  };

  return {
    connection,
    connect,
    connectToMessageServer,
    connectionStatus,
    disconnectFromMessageServer,
  };
};```




can any one help me identifying my problem?

I was expecting to know the states of the server whether it is connected or disconnected. but currently the error is displaying when the connect function is excuted
````